# Punching someone and sending them flying at the speed of sound

Tags: physics, hard-science, martial-arts

How much force/energy is required to punch someone so hard that the person is sent flying at the speed of sound?

Also, what can you compare the force/energy to? For example, is it comparable to a TNT explosion or something?

Edit: Hypothetically assume these beings were superhuman that can survive such attacks.

Comment: If you are punching a human being that hard, whatever you're hitting them with will go through them, not send them flying.

Comment: I think you need to provide some more details. As already pointed out, a punch would smash through a person.

Comment: E = (mv^2)/2. Do the math.

Comment: [Muzzle energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muzzle_energy)

Comment: I'm pretty sure at those energies a human body would not so much "fly" as "splash".

Comment: please clarify the average weight of the targets of this punch and ill do my best to get you an accurate estimate

Comment: @Elias Rowan Albatross - We need to know whether they vibrate or fold and whether they spin. If the victim is hit on the jaw and the puncher strikes from the shoulder, then both the puncher and punchee will spin backwards and a lot of the energy will be absorbed by the spin.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I understand your point, but I don't understand how this is relevant to what I just asked. I just want to know what size of people we're dealing with.

Comment: Hajhar, if the punchee were made of steel tempered to be springy and the puncher had an arm which could contact the punchee and then extend a few metres whilst accelerating them - does this fit your scenario?

Comment: @chasly at these speeds, a punch to the jaw would decapitate. Even at normal speeds a blow to the jaw will dissipate its energy through crushing (the jaw) before spin is imputed. A spin can be accomplished with a really good kick to the occipital bone (much more robust than the jaw) - I know because I was on the receiving end of one of those in a tournament once - but only at the high end of "normal" speeds. At mach speeds it would be a slightly less messy decapitation.

Comment: @pojo-guy - Yes but the OP says assume these are superhumans who can survive this sort of thing.

Comment: Even if they weren't superhumans, the punch could just accelerate for a really long time and accelerate them to the speed of sound very slowly.

Comment: @user45266 - That's a push not a punch! It also require very long arms!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Or a human standing on a slowly accelerating vehicule. Depending on how you define "punch", this could work (a punch is a push from a human's hand made with a closed fist).

Answer (score 4):

Suposing speed of sound of 340m/s (sea height normal pressure) a 100kg man (because a 153cm tall superhuman doesn't really cut it), which is a good suposition for a strong, tall man, you'll need about 6 Megajoules of energy (I've rounded up to account for that hard mistress, 2nd law of thermodynamics, and because you need to *surpass* the speed of sound, even if just by a little bit).

How to deliver this energy without destroying parts of the body of both the puncher and the punched, and without loosing any more energy in heat, spin or other possible non-intended consequences is left as an exercise to the OP.

Also, if you want to compare it to an explosive, that's like a little over a kilogram of TNT.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need some metrics first.

The average adult human being is between 60 kg and 80 kg. For this question we will average this as 70 kg.

Let's also assume that the attacker's fist is in contact with the enemy for 0.5 seconds. The less time the fist is in contact with the enemy, the more force will need to be exerted in order to accelerate the enemy to the desired speed.

---

As a variant on Newton's second law, the required force is given by the following equation:
$$F = m \times \frac { v_{f}-v_{i}}{t}$$
where:

- $m=$ the mass of the object $=70\space kg$
- $v_i=$ the initial velocity $=0\space m/s$
- $v_f=$ the final velocity $=343\space m/s =$ speed of sound
- $t=$ the time it took to change the velocity $=0.5 \space s$
- $F=$ the force required, measured in Newtons

  ---

Now let's plug the data into the equation:
$$F = 70 \times \frac { 343-0}{0.5}= 70 \times \frac { 343}{0.5}$$

$$F = 70 \times { 686} = 48020‬ N$$

---

So we arrive at our answer.

## It takes 48020 N, or around 10,795 pounds of force.

> The force applied by the engine of a small car during peak acceleration

---

If you want a quicker punch, I have assembled the following table for consultation:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
  Time \space (s) & Force \space (N) & Force \space (lbs)\\
  0.5 & 48,020 & 10,795.3‬ \\
  0.25 & 96,040 & 21,590.6‬ \\
  0.1 & 240,100 & 53,976.6‬ \\
\end{array}
 $$

---

Or, if you prefer to choose the amount time for the fist to be in contact with the enemy, you may use the following formulas:
$F= \frac {24010}{t} $ for Newtons and $F= \frac {5397.66272}{t} $ for pounds of force.